# Getting 401 Unauthorized Xero oAuth 2.0 -

Tags: php, laravel, oauth-2.0, xero-api

I am trying to create a new contact using Xero oAuth 2.0 and getting this error:

```
[401] Client error: `PUT https://api.xero.com/api.xro/2.0/Contacts?summarizeErrors=true` resulted in a `401 Unauthorized` response:
```

I have got my scopes as:

```
'scopes'   => [
            'openid',
            'email',
            'profile',
            'offline_access',
            'accounting.settings',
            'accounting.contacts',
            'accounting.reports.read',
        ],
```

I am able to connect to Xero ([using this code](https://github.com/webfox/laravel-xero-oauth2#using-the-package)) and I get message **The App is connected to Xero** but when I use the following code:-

```
public function xeroTest(OauthCredentialManager $xeroCredentials) {

        $apiInstance  = resolve(\XeroAPI\XeroPHP\Api\AccountingApi::class);
        $contact = resolve( \XeroAPI\XeroPHP\Models\Accounting\Contact::class);
        $contact->setName('Abcdef');
        $contact->setContactId('6d42f03b-181f-43e3-93fb-2025c0hjhe92');

        $apiResponse = $apiInstance->createContacts($xeroCredentials->getTenantId() ,$contact,true);
        $message = 'New Contact Name: ' . $apiResponse->getContacts()[0]->getName();

        return $message;
    }
```

Error:
[401] Client error: `PUT https://api.xero.com/api.xro/2.0/Contacts?summarizeErrors=true` resulted in a `401 Unauthorized` response:

Comment: How did you solve this issue? I got the same one.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see all your code but you likely just have to set the valid **access_token** on the PHP client.

https://github.com/XeroAPI/xero-php-oauth2#callbackphp

Comment: I have updated my question and added the complete function. How do I add a callback using a laravel framework. can u please point me to the right direction. Thanks

Comment: Hi @user10345537 - i think your best bet is to file an issue with that repo you are using. You need to set the access token on the client somehow but I am not familiar with that code.